# Optional multiple map vs single map

Tags: java, option-type, fold

I am working with `Optional` quiet a while now and I am wondering which way performs better.

```
Optional<String> path = Optional.of("LoremIp.sum")

Optional<BufferedReader> reader1 = 
  path.map(File::new)
      .map(FileReader::new)
      .map(BufferedReader::new)

Optional<BufferedReader> reader2 =
   path.map(file -> 
     new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File())
   )
```

Readability is arguable in my example and may depend on formatting, but that is not my question here.

The creation of `reader1` appeals to me as a more functional style, but it seems to me, as if it creates more intermediate `Optional` objects. Precisely it should create a new `Optional` for each call to `map`.

The creation of `reader2` uses `Supplier`, which I understood as inferior to using the `Function` interface, but have no source to prove so.

Can anybody provide a good source for performance differences in both approaches?

Comment: Run them in a loop and put a timer on it.

Comment: I am not sure, if the the compiler may optimize those calls, if they appear multiple times. But as a naive heuristic, this might work.